# how can i add Uiimagepickerview in tabbaritem?

Tags: iphone

how can i add Uiimagepickerview in tabbaritem like this image.Kindly go through the below link to view the image.. i need like this image.so pls help me.
http://artoftheiphone.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/ShopSavvy-Barcode-Sacnner.png

Comment: You really need to add more context to this question.  Do you want it in a view that a tab bar shows?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they're adding the UIImagePickerView to the tabbar, I think they're adding the tabbar as a subview of the UIImagePickerView. The UIImagePickerController has support for an accessory view. I think they create an accessory view that duplicates the tabbar and they display that.

You pretty much have to do it that way because the image picker presents modally.

Comment: could u give me the code to create an accessory view that duplicates the tabbar.It would be more helpful for me.